# Tool for parsing querystrings, creating URL encoded params etc?

Tags: c#, firefox, query-string, urlencode, querystringparameter

before writing my own :-)

I was wondering if anyone knows a tool to parse a URL and extract all the params into a easier viewable format, a grid maybe? (these urls are extremely long :- )

And also if it allows you to construct the querystring for standard text and automates the URL ENCODING etc.

Must be one available, i have searched high and low and can't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not. And don't use very long querystring :) It's better to use some Session object to keep all data u need instead of using a querystring.

Comment: Have you tried the URIParser?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser.aspx

Comment: https://devtechfactory.com/url-encode-decode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method is pretty handy for those tasks.

> I was wondering if anyone knows a tool to parse a URL and extract all
>   the params into a easier viewable format, a grid maybe? (these urls
>   are extremely long :- )

```
using System;
using System.Web;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://foo.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2");
        var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
        foreach (string key in values.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, value: {1}", key, values[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

> And also if it allows you to construct the querystring for standard
>   text and automates the URL ENCODING etc.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        values["param1"] = "value1";
        values["param2"] = "value2";
        var builder = new UriBuilder("http://foo.com");
        builder.Query = values.ToString();
        var url = builder.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
}
```